# Folder location / path issue

Tags: network-shares, path, shared-folders, windows-server-2019

I am a learning junior sys admin and I read an article on how to give a shared drive over the network a recycling bin in a roundabout way...I was told if i change the file path of a random folder in my user folder (i.e. contacts) to the folder on the network drive that i was looking to add a recyling bin to, that it would allow me to delete things from the network folder and they would appear in my local recycling bin. This actually worked, however it only works on a per user basis as i found out. However, we decided to not go ahead with this change.

But now this is where the problem lies... That shared folder on the network now is displayed as "Contacts" locally and it has the contact folder icon. I tried going back into the contacts folder and changing the path back to default or "C:\users"user"\contacts but the location tab in the properties tab is missing. Now, luckily the share on the actual server is still named the appropriate name but on my server i don't know how to fix this.

I've read that it's an issue where I might have to go into the registry and add a key to the properties sheet directory? There's a ton of data in this folder and on this server and I'm worried this small change might have caused an issue. So far all the data is in tact and nobody who uses the share has authentication or connection issues but it's still a problem.

Can someone help?

Here is a picture of the active share which still holds the folder name correctly. [Share Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpEjg.jpg)

Here is a picture of the contacts folder which no longer has the locations tab after I changed the path. [Contacts folder with no location tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRbCN.jpg)

And here is a picture of the actual object (the folder with all of my data) that is correctly labeled with the object name in the "security" tab. But without going into the properties and just looking at it within file explorer now shows the "contacts" folder. [Incorrectly named folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myILb.jpg)

Comment: We can’t help you without understanding what you did exactly

Comment: What was unclear?

Comment: Do you have some picture to add for clarification ?

Comment: @iliightly - You were not specific in what you actually did; to move the network share to a folder within your profile location like Contracts. My first instinct is to say delete the user profile on the machine.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added some pictures for clarification. So the network share is in tact and that was untouched. I believe I was unclear as to what change was actually made. There is a share created for a specific folder let's call it "X". So "X" is shared out  currently. My issue is where I went into my Shell user folder "Contacts". I went into the location tab and changed the path set to folder "X". The path used to be C:\users\(user)\Contacts. But now that location tab is missing and I cant simple change it back. It's caused my "X" folder to display the name Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

here the path to change the default location

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

But even if you change it, maybe the problem can remain again because of Windows logic.

Comment: Yes I tried that and no luck, also I tried to add the location tab back to sheet properties and still cant find it. Now im looking for the contact folder and its just disappeared totally.